# How to pass not encoded json data to fullcalendar in mvc3?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin -

```
//c#
 public JsonResult Events(int start, int end) // GetEvents return an array of my DTO
        {
            return Json(GetEvents(ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(start), ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(end)),  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          }

//html
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
       $(document).ready(function () {        
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            month: 5,
            year: 2011,
            editable: false,
            events: 'MyWebsite/Events'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is the data is getting encoded, so I want to pass something like `"<b>Name</b>"` it gets encoded. So, I tried serializing with [AllowHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute but does not work also I have tried bunch of other things. What I need to do is somehow call [serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) object without the encoding which I guess by default..or at least skip encoding for the one field with `AllowHtml` data annotation ? I have a looked at a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor).

Can anyone give me any help here I cannot really use [Html.Raw()](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) as I see it since I am passing the data to javascript I guess it just needs to be somehow decoded.

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you will have to edit the fullcalendar.min.js or the fullcalendar.js file whichever that you have included and search for

```
"<span class='fc-event-title'>" + Ka(Q.title) + "</span></a>"
```

then add bold tags as follows

```
"<span class='fc-event-title'><b>" + Ka(Q.title) + "</b></span></a>"
```