# Invalid property ID error - JSON object from List<> c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json, razor

I've been on this for a couple of days now and getting nowhere.

I'm trying to serialize a List object to JSON so it can be passed to Google Analytics' e-commerce service, so it needs to get passed into javascript beforehand.

However, there is an error with the json output.

First of all I have an Item class.

```
Item {
    Id,
    Name,
    Sku,
    Price,
    Quantity
}
```

My cart class contains a List of Items

```
public List<Item> Items;
```

I'm using the following to serialize the list.

```
var jsonList = JavascriptSerializer.Serialize(cart.Items);
```

jsonList is then passed into javascript using Razor like so -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = @jsonList;
</script>
```

The result that is generated in the browser looks like this:

```
items = [{&quot;Id&quot;:ITEM_ID,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;ITEM_NAME&quot;,&quot;Sku&quot;:&quot;ITEM_SKU&quot;,&quot;Quantity&quot;:ITEM_QTY,&quot;Price&quot;:ITEM_PRICE},{&quot;Id&quot;:ITEM2_ID,&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;ITEM2_NAME&quot;,etc...}]
```

So I'd like to know how I get rid of the &quot and replace them with the required " instead.
Does it have something to do with my Item class or my javascript?

I've tried @Html.Raw(items) and no luck - returns an empty json object.

Comment: I believe that you should change the title of your question

Comment: Why is that @AndreCalil? The output of the items variable causes the invalid property ID on the first &quot;

Comment: Your question is "how do I remove the `&quot`" and your title states a different problem.

Comment: Sorry @AndreCalil, I would argue that the error in the title (Invalid property ID error) was caused by the &quot being displayed in the json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that worked on the following post.

[How do I write unencoded Json to my View using Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor)

Thanks to @James for mentioning unencoded HTML - that put me on the right path.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) to return unencoded HTML

```
var items = @Html.Raw(@jsonList);
```

Comment: Thanks @James but unfortunately that does not work. It simply returns an empty json object