# Convert MVC4 Model into javascript json object on cshtml page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model in my cshtml page and I want to covert this model into json object so that I may use this json in javascript that is on cshtml page it self. I am using MVC4.

How I can do that?

Comment: You can use [`Json.Encode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode.aspx) as described in [How do I write unencoded Json to my View using Razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - That is deprecated. MVC 4 uses `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Comment: @TravisJ Where is it documented as deprecated? The [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.aspx) and [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.aspx) don't list it as "Obsolete."

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - I was mistaken. It is not deprecated. I thought that it was still using JavaScriptSerializer but it turns out that it uses the default Json serializer which is Json.NET in mvc4 so that all works out.

Answer (score 8):

***[`.NET Fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yU4ayH)***

What you are looking for is called "Serialization". MVC 4 uses Json.NET by default. The syntax is very easy to use. In order to have access to the library in your view model, use

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Once you have used that, the syntax for serializing is like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
```

After serializing the string, you may use the json in your view like this:

```
var viewModel = @Html.Raw(json);
```

Here is a more in depth example:

Model.cs

```
public class SampleViewModel : AsSerializeable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<NestedData> NestedData { get; set; }
    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        this.Name = "Serialization Demo";
        this.NestedData = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(i => new NestedData(i)).ToList();   
    }
}

public class NestedData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public NestedData(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;   
    }
}

public abstract class AsSerializeable
{
    public string ToJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SampleViewModel());
    }
}
```

View.cshtml

```
    <body>
    <div>
        <h1 id="Name"></h1>
        <div id="Data"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Load serialized model
    var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());

    //use view model
    $("#Name").text(viewModel.Name);

    var dataSection = $("#Data");
    $.each(viewModel.NestedData,function(){
        dataSection.append("<div>id: "+this.Id+"</div>");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I love the fact that you put `ToJson()` on the base class. Thank you!