# How mvc framework parse objects to JavaScript object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I pass some data (reference type or value type) in action function using ViewBag or ViewData.

The passed data (in ViewData or ViewBag) I assigned it to JavaScript variable on client side:

```
var stuff = @ViewBag.somedata;
```

My question is what the type of the variable **stuff** it will be? Is it JavaScript object? or string? or maybe string in JSON format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write unencoded Json to my View using Razor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what the type of the variable stuff it will be?

Javascript has types now? [Yes it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), but I don't think that is the question you want answered. Furthermore your question lacks lots of detail about what *exactly* you want to do. Where does the data come from? What do you want to do with it? Why do you want to assign it to a Javascript variable?

Anyway, this:

```
var stuff = @ViewBag.somedata;
```

Will only work if `@ViewBag.somedata` contains a number (depending on culture though) or object whose `.ToString()` representation is valid Javascript.

Razor has no notion of Javascript. Values you print will be html-encoded. If `ViewBag.somedata` contains a number, your HTML will go look like this:

```
var stuff = 42;
```

When it's a decimal and your culture uses comma for that:

```
var stuff = 4,2;
```

If it contains a string, it'll look like this:

```
var stuff = Hello, world!;
```

And if it by some magic contains a valid Javascript object initializer:

```
var stuff = { foo: bar };
```

But usually, it'll just print the type name for a reference type:

```
var stuff = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[string];
```

Almost all examples above won't work. So you'll want to use quotes:

```
var stuff = '@ViewBag.somedata';
```

But then still your data will be HTML-encoded, so if you want to convert a C# reference type to JSON and assign that to a Javascript variable, do as explained in [How do I write unencoded Json to my View using Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor):

```
var stuff = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PotentialAttendees));
```

Comment: thanks for this good explanation!But what if ViewBag.somedata contains json string format?Do I have to use json encode anyway?

Answer (score 1):

It will be string. You may have to use `eval` if you want convert that into javascript recognizable.

Comment: eval? I am using razor engine.