# Doubles from ViewModel get rounded to ints in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, razor, rounding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have this code (@Model.TW is 11,58 and @Model.TK is 27,65)(both doubles):

```
var parameters = [@Model.TW,@Model.TK];
```

When checking parameters[0] and [1] the double values are rounded to 11 and 27. Why is this?

The same happens when just doing

```
var double = [@Model.TW];
```

or

```
var double = parseFloat('[@Model.TW]');
```

even if the return types of @Model.xx are changed to string there is no difference.

Comment: Try `[parseDouble('@Model.TW')]` - probably parsing as an int

Comment: is it because the browser is using a different culture?  If I use `[11.58, 27.65]`, it works for me using standard en-US OS settings.  Is yours going to 4 values: `[11, 58, 27, 65]` ?

Comment: tried parsefloat, no results.  @ps2goat No the value order is fine, the values just get rounded to ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float values passed to JavaScript as JSON or direct values *must* have "." as decimal separator. Some cultures use "," and thus parsing of such numbers as JSON or with `parseFloat` will fail to recognize decimal part.

Fix: use invariant culture to format numbers or use existing libraries (like Json.Net) to produce JSON.

```
var parameters = [@(Model.TW.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
     @(Model.TK.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))];
```

JSON sample can be found at - [How do I write unencoded Json to my View using Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor)