# Where are @Json.Encode or @Json.Decode methods in MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

What is equivalent of MVC5's `@Json.Encode` method in MVC6? In MVC5 we can access those methods in views. But I can't find any methods which I can access from MVC 6 views.

I don't want to write a helper method if there is already a built in feature in MVC6.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

After some search, found it:

```
@inject IJsonHelper Json;
@Json.Serialize(...)
```

Comment: Special care should be taken to avoid passing unsanitized user data through this, as it may cause XSS vulnerabilities

Comment: I don't know if this has changed but with ASP.Net Core 2.1, I don't need to inject Json. It's just there already

Answer (score 19):

I've had success with the following:

```
@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj) as String)
```

I'm not sure if Json.Encode has made it in yet because it was a part of System.Web which is gone now.

Comment: Note that this won't pick up any default options specified using AddJsonOptions() during startup however injecting IJsonHelper will.

Answer (score 12):

One of the features of `@Json.Encode()` was automatic HTML encoding of entities within JSON strings, which is helpful to avoid XSS vulnerabilities. The [`JsonHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.jsonhelper) class is based on Json.NET serialization now, which does support at least some (or all) of this same functionality if configured properly. The other solutions here can be vulnerable to XSS attacks if untrusted data is serialized.

Quick example of a vulnerability:

```
<script>
    window.something = @Json.Serialize(new { someprop = "Hello</script><script>alert('xss')</script><script>" });
</script>
```

Will be rendered as

```
<script>
    window.something = {"someprop":"Hello
</script>
<script>alert('xss')</script>
<script>"};</script>
```

To properly configure Json.NET to escape HTML entities would be to use the [`@Json.Serialize(object, serializerSettings)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.jsonhelper.serialize) overload and override StringEscapeHandling to EscapeHTML. The settings could be defined in a helper class or injected.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
<script>
    @{
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml};
    }
    window.something = @Json.Serialize(new { someprop = "Hello</script><script>alert('xss')</script><script>" }, settings);
</script>
```

Which is rendered instead as:

```
<script>
    window.something = {"someprop":"Hello\u003c/script\u003e\u003cscript\u003ealert(\u0027xss\u0027)\u003c/script\u003e\u003cscript\u003e"};
</script>
```

Some other methods of safely serializing data to the page in ASP.NET Core can be found here: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/cross-site-scripting.md