# Asp net core MVC: Passing a list of string as a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, list, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using google api to show a map. In my controller I wrote the following c# code:

```
var sedi = new List<string>();
sedi.Add("Via Gavinana, 19, Roma");
sedi.Add("Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi");
sedi.Add("Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait");
ViewBag.sediList = sedi;
return View(ViewBag.sediList);
```

In my view:

```
@{
    var vb  = (List<string>)ViewBag.sediList;
}
function GetLatLon (address, callback) {
    console.log(address);
    var location = new Array();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            location = { lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng() };
            callback(location);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

function addMarker (location, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

function initMap() {
    GetLatLon("@vb", function(location) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: location
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           addMarker(location, map);
        }
    });
  }
```

And I want show three markers on map corresponding to the location written in the list `vb`
But address has `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` value and not the real value of the address.
How can I pass the list as parameter to the `GetLatLon` function in Javascript? How can I fix?

**EDIT**

I need to show three marker on the map, foreach address.
I write:

```
function GetLatLonByAddress (address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            location = { lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng() };
            return location;
            console.log (location);
        } 
        return;
    });
}

function initMap() {
    GetLatLon('@(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model‌​.Maps)))', function(location) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: location
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           addMarker('@(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model‌​.Maps)))', map, i);
        }
    });
  }

function addMarker (location, map, count) {
    var locationArr = JSON.parse(location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: GetLatLonByAddress(locationArr[count]),
        map: map
    });
}
```

Is it possible something like this? How can I fix?

Comment: return View(ViewBag.sediList); - looks a bit strange. If you are using ViewBag and there is no model on View - you need return View(). If there is a model, containing the sediList - then you don't need a ViewBag. Just pass the data through the model

Comment: GetLatLon("@vb", function(location)  - and here you pass string, but not an array

Comment: You need to assign it to a javascript variable - `var vn = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.sediList))';` which will be an array of your 3 address strings. But change your code to delete `ViewBag.sediList = sedi;` and use `return View(sedi);` and in the view add `@model List<string>` then use `'@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';`

Comment: @StephenMuecke what reference do I need to add in my project.json to use Encode method?

Comment: @FabioBit System.Web.Mvc

Comment: @FabioBit, For mvc core, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301930/where-are-json-encode-or-json-decode-methods-in-mvc-6)

Comment: I had tried it but it give me the same issue: it pass the string [&quot;Via Gavinana, 19,Roma, &quot;,&quot;Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi&quot;,&quot;Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait&quot;] and not the array object. How can I fix? @StephenMuecke

Comment: @FabioBit, I assume from the comments in Boris Sokolov's answer that this is now solved?

Comment: yes @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could create:

**Model**

```
public class MapsModel
{
    public MapsModel(string[] maps)
    {
        Maps = maps;
    }

    public string[] Maps { get; private set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MapsController : Controller
{
   // GET: MapsModel
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        var model = new MapsModel(
                new[]
                {
                    "Via Gavinana, 19, Roma",
                    "Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi",
                    "Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait"
                } 
            );

      return View(model);
   }
}
```

**View**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MapsModel
```

...

```
function initMap() {
   GetLatLon('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Maps))', function (location) {
```

...

And you don't need ViewBag for such cases.

Comment: How can I change `GetLatLon('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Maps))', function (location) {` using `@Json.Serialize(...)` for aspnet core?

Comment: You could try to use some 3rd-parties like '@Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Maps)'

Comment: I had tried it but it give me the same issue: it pass the string `[&quot;Via Gavinana, 19, Busto Arsizio, VA&quot;,&quot;Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi&quot;,&quot;Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait&quot;]` and not the array object.

Comment: because it returns string, but not HtmlString. There should be kind of HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Maps))... JsonHelper.Serialize should solve this issue as well. It should be a part of Asp.net core v5

Comment: Can I use `HtmlString` like a cast in this way?

Comment: `GetLatLon("@HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Maps))", function(location) {`

Comment: GetLatLon('@(new HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Maps)))', function (location) {

Comment: What's the nuget package for System.Web namespace to include in my project.json file?

Comment: I fixed with `GetLatLon('@(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model‌​.Maps)))', function(location) {` but it returns the same string

Comment: What kind of string does it return? I have ["Via Gavinana, 19, Roma","Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi","Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait"] for new HtmlString(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model‌​.Maps))

Comment: Yes that's the same for me

Comment: So that's should be ok. Or do you need smth different? it is just the same as '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))'

Comment: Yes but How can I handle the object in GetLatLon function?

Comment: It is just an array... var array = ["Via Gavinana, 19, Roma","Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi","Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait"];
for (var s in array) {
    document.write(array[s]);
}

Comment: I wanted to mean that in this way the first item of array is `[` and not `Via Gavinana, 19, Roma`. How can I fix?

Comment: My code is: `function GetLatLon (address, callback) {
        console.log(address);
        for (var s in address) {
            console.log(address[s]);
        }`

Comment: var addressArray = JSON.parse(address);
         for (var s in addressArray)
         { console.log(addressArray[s]); }

Comment: center: location - here you need one address, but not an array. You could try to call the fist element there for instance

Comment: Fixed: `center: location[0]` but how can I use callback function to return coordinates value into a location var?

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the best approach but you can use this quick solution.

Controller:=>

```
var sedi = new List<string>();
sedi.Add("Via Gavinana, 19, Roma");
sedi.Add("Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi");
sedi.Add("Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait");
ViewBag.sediList = Json.Encode(sedi);

// No need to pass the viewbag in View param
return View();
```

View :=>

```
 var vb = @ViewBag.sediList;
 for(var i=0;i<vb.length;i++){
  GetLatLon (vb[i],function(){});
 }

 function GetLatLon (address, callback) {
    console.log(address);
    var location = new Array();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            location = { lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(), lng: results[0].geometry.location.lng() };
            callback(location);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

function addMarker (location, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

function initMap() {
    GetLatLon("@vb", function(location) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 2,
            center: location
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           addMarker(location, map);
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use it something like this:
in your controller:

```
var sedi = new List<string>();
sedi.Add("Via Gavinana, 19, Roma");
sedi.Add("Val de Seine, 94600 Choisy le Roi");
sedi.Add("Street 21,Shuwaikh, Kuwait");
var sediString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sedi);
ViewBag.sediList = sediString;
return View();
```

in your view put a hidden for using it in java script:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sediString" name="sediString" value="@ViewBag.sediList">
```

and in your java script use it like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#sediString").val());
```

and you can have your data in array and use it in javascript each function:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
//enter your code
}
```

**Edit1:**
for javascript not jquery use:

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById(sediString).val());
```

instead of

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#sediString").val());
```

and  use normal for instead of $.each

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       addMarker(data[i], map);
    }
```

**Edit2:**

you don't need hidden input for accessing view bag in java script.
you can use it in javascript:

```
var data = JSON.parse(@ViewBag.sediList);
```

Comment: Can you rewrite it using "normal" javascript code and not jquery please?

Comment: Why do you use hidden fields here? This approach is not smth that should be used in MVC

Comment: @BorisSokolov because i want to have access to data that send from controller in my javascript. the data must be somewhere to have it in javascript

Comment: But it has access to Model or ViewBag in this sample.