# MVC Razor variable has "." removed for a ViewModel Double Variable

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, double, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a `PartialView` which is using my `ViewModel`: `LatLonSpeedViewModel`

## LatLonSpeedViewModel:

```
public class LatLonSpeedViewModel
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double sp { get; set; }
}
```

## PartialView:

```
@model List<LatLonSpeedViewModel>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    function initMap(){
        ... setting map code

        var geojson = []

        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            @:geojson.push(@(item.lat), @(item.lon), @(item.sp));
            //This is not how I generate my geojson object, but just for illustration
        }
    }
</script>
```

My problem is that the dot from the double variables seem to get truncated/removed.

If I do a `@:console.log(@(item.lat));` or `@:console.log(@(item.lon));` it prints out the variables as `5 32145131` and `75 3215131`. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Use `var data = @Html.Raw(JSON.Encode(Model));` to first convert your model to a javascript array and then loop through that array.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get an error doing this: `'IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' acception a first argument of type 'IJsonHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: `IJsonHelper`? Is this asp.net-core-mvc?

Comment: Yup. Probably should have added that to my question.

Comment: Have re-tagged it. Also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301930/where-are-json-encode-or-json-decode-methods-in-mvc-6)

Comment: Would need to be `var data = '@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model))';` I think

Comment: @StephenMuecke `var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));` did the trick. Thanks. The single quotes didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I addded

```
@inject IJsonHelper Json;
```

to my `_ViewImports.cshtml`

and then I could do the following to iterate through my data:

```
var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
$.each(jsonData, function(key, value) {
    geojson.push(value.lat, value.lon, value.sp);
    //as with the question this is not how I add to my 
    //geojson object, but merely for illustration of how
    //to access the values
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just make the model a json object

```
<script>
var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

$(jsonData).each(function(){
//Whatever you want 
})
</Script>
```

Comment: I get an error: `JsonEncode`does not exist in the current context`