# MVC Core Retrieve ListOfNames from Controller to View, so View can accessed the List and do JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

need help here.
May I know if I did anything wrong. Apparently, it's not working.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{

    var data = new List<String>();
    data.Add("No");
    data.Add("Yes");
    data.Add("543");


    ViewBag.Name= data;
    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
        function Validation(IsValid) {
         var test = '@ViewBag.Name';
         var a = "Yes"
         for (var z = 0; z < test.length; z++)
         {
           if (a == test[z]) {
           ...then..
           }
         }
        }
```

How do I accessed the "No", "Yes", and "543" inside the JavaScript?

Comment: `var test = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Name))` to convert your model to a javascript array.

Comment: Suggest you also learn some basics of debugging your scripts using your browser tools. Even a basic `console.log(test);` would make it clear where the issue is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the update. May I know how to solve the problem of "Cannot resolve symbol Encode" ?

Comment: Just noticed you have `IActionResult` which means you should have tagged this [tag:asp.net-core-mvc]. In which case refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301930/where-are-json-encode-or-json-decode-methods-in-mvc-6) for the equivalent of `Json.Encode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    function Validation(IsValid) {
        var test = '@(string.Join(",",((List<string>)ViewBag.Name)))'.split(",");
        var a = "Yes"
        for (var z = 0; z < test.length; z++)
        {
            if (a == test[z]) {
                //...then..
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But it's still not working

Comment: What issue is coming? It is working perfectly in my test project.

Comment: thanks for your help. Its working perfectly fine.

Comment: I have one request, if ((Object.values(Names).indexOf(name[1].value) > -1). How do I make it to Lowercase? Because the "Names" object the string is all lower case. Thanks!