# how to send generic list with json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have generic list to view.

```
List<Student> StudentList = ViewBag.StudentList;
```

I want send this list with JSON.

```
var listSTD = @StudentList;
var id = 5;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Students/Check",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"listSTD": listSTD, "id": id},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result.Result);
        }
    });
```

but is not working. get error in this code:

> var listSTD = @StudentList;

Comment: and the error is.....?

Comment: `= @StudentList;` is clearly invalid. The view has access to the model, the Temp dictionary and the ViewBag. If you want to access something from the ViewBag use the same syntax you use in C#, eg `@ViewBag.StudentList`. Everything after that `@` is C#  code

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be passing the `List<Student` object directly to your script as the object is not in a format js can read or work with so you need to JSON serialize the object into a JSON string which you can then include in the data body of your post request.

You can serialize the object with `Newtonsoft.Json` and you need to make sure the `listSTD` variable is instantiated inline when the view is rendered rather than in an external file (the rest of your code can be in an external js file). For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    @{ List<Student> StudentList = ViewBag.StudentList; }

    <script>
       var listSTD = "@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StudentList)";
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

On the server-side controller action responding to your post request at `/Students/Check` you can de-serialize the posted student list JSON back into `List<Student>` For example in your controller action:

```
public class StudentsController
{
  public ActionResult Check(StudentsCheckViewModel model)
  {
     int id = model.id;
     List<Student> Students = Json.DeserializeObject<List<Student>>(model.listSTD);
  }
}
```

And the view model:

```
public class StudentsCheckViewModel 
{
   public int id { get; set; }

   public string listSTD { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the json action input with this code? i using this but send null list in action.

Comment: @mishicaro you didn't ask anything about actions. You asked how to emit a JSON array into the view

Comment: Do you have `Newtonsoft.Json`? If not, the resulting serialized JSON string will probably null or error. Install in nuget by: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: I want use this list in input action in /Students/Check.

Comment: not error in code. but send or give empty null list. i use List<Student> type in input json action in "/Students/Check" address

Comment: Might be an issue in your controller action? Your ajax post request looks fine assuming you're passing the JSON serialized string `listSTD` instead of the actual object. You may need to change your action view model if you're using one since the listSTD will be a string

Comment: I've updated it with a controller action and view model example. If the `listSTD` is still null you may need to check if its value is actually being passed to the script successfully before ajax posting

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the data as JSON into the view using the JSON helper, eg :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var rowData = @Json.Serialize(Model.Rows);
    ...

</script>
```

In older versions you may have to use `Json.Encode` or wrap the call in `Html.Raw`, eg `@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(...))`

Comment: I do not have Serialize method. and use Encode but not working...

Comment: @mishicaro I copied that code from my own project. Which ASP.NET MVC version are you using and what does `not working` mean? What do you see in the page source?

Comment: @mishicaro ASP.NET MVC 6 does have Json.Serialize as shown [in this possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301930/where-are-json-encode-or-json-decode-methods-in-mvc-6)