# C# MVC - Passing a List from C# backend to JavaScript

Tags: list, model-view-controller, model

im new to the MVC pattern and got a problem passing variables to JS from C#.

Im passing a List from the viewmodel to the view that im storing in a hidden variable:

`<input type="hidden" id="myID" name="myID" value="@Model.myList">`

Then when im trying to grab this variable in JS:

`const myList = document.getElementById("myID").value;`

But then I get a System.Collections.Generic.List that I cant do anything with. How can i make it so that I can reach this List in JS?

Answer (score 1):

The default string representation of an object in .NET is the class name.  You don't want a string, you want the actual object itself.  In this case it sounds like what you're looking to do is JSON-encode the data.  So you wouldn't need an `<input>` at all, you can do that directly in the JavaScript code in your view:

```
const myList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.myList));
```

This would result in `myList` in your JavaScript being the array of objects from the `myList` property on your server-side model.

Comment: Thank you for your respone. I get an error message saying: 'IJsonHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Encode' and no extension method 'Encode' accepting a first argument of type 'IJsonHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ziBBit: Hmm... It could change drastically depending on MVC version.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301930/where-are-json-encode-or-json-decode-methods-in-mvc-6) seems to offer some suggestions for other MVC versions.  Same concept, just different place to call it.