# Using Razor and javascript within each other

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use a javascript variable in Razor like this :

my html:

```
@{List<AddTempViewModel> tempsToView = new List<AddTempViewModel>();
  tempsToView = (List<AddTempViewModel>)ViewData["tempsToView"];}

@if (tempsToView != null)
{
    @foreach (var item in tempsToView)
    {
       <a class="click" id="@item.TempDocumentId">
       <img id="leftSideBarElement" src="@item.TempDocumentAddressUrl" />
       </a><br />
    }
<form method="post" action="">
   <input id="documentNumber" class="form-control" type="text" name=""  
     placeholder="Email" />
 </form>
```

and my script :

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".click").click(function () {
            var divID = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(divID);
            var docName = @tempsToView[divID].TempDocumentId
            $("#documentNumber").val(docName);
        });
    });
</script>
```

but I can't set the index of @tempsToView with divID.
please help me what to do except this.
thank you.

Comment: Can you post rest of the relevant the view code?

Comment: Are you trying to set the value of `documentNumber` to your `@tempsToView[].TempDocumentId` property? If so why are you not specifying the index of the array?

Comment: Because it generate after compilation.I want to dynamically set the index of that list.

Comment: You can JSON encode your razor model or the specific property. Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a Razor variable based on something that's happening in JavaScript. Razor runs server-side, while JavaScript runs client-side, after all Razor has already been run.

Comment: So what do you suggest me to do except this?

Comment: There's nothing you can do other than change your code to approach the problem in a different way. You haven't given any details on what you're actually trying to achieve here, but basically, if you need access to the data behind `@tempsToView` in the JavaScript runtime, you'll either need to set some JavaScript variable to hold that data earlier in your code or use AJAX to retrieve it after the fact.

Comment: Actually I fill a list in a controller and send that to its view. I have a tag that I want when it is clicked set some values into an input tag. What should i do except this?

Comment: Again, you either need to dump the contents of `tempsToView` into a JavaScript variable that you can reference later, or use AJAX to fetch the appropriate data remotely at a later point based on some index value.

Comment: ok, but can you help me with some codes? or introduce a site ?

Answer (score 2):

Its not really clear what you need but If I get you right... I used to make this mix of Razor and Js but in the long run I realize 2 things:

- It looks pretty ugly
- It won't run if you move your js code to a separate .js file, because
  the Razor engine does not process JS files.

So a simple and elegant solution would be to use data attributes:

```
 @foreach (var item in tempsToView)
        {
           <a class="click" id="@item.TempDocumentId" 
             data-document-name="@item.TempDocumentName"
             data-document-isbn="@item.TempDocumentIsbn">
           <img id="leftSideBarElement" src="@item.TempDocumentAddressUrl" />
           </a><br />
        }
```

And then just get the data-property you need like:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".click").click(function () {
        var divID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(divID);
        var docName = $(this).attr('data-document-name');
        var docIsbn = $(this).attr('data-document-isbn');
        //and any other property you may need
        $("#documentNumber").val(docName);
    });
});
```

That way you keep, all your HTML/Razor and JS separate, and still functional, a clean code and every element is self-sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var divID = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(divID);
        var documentName = $(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempsToView )))[divID];
        console.log(documentName);
    });

</script>
```