# How to save JSON from an ASP.NET viewmodel into a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page that loads a viewmodel. In the viewmodel is a single property that contains a blob of JSON:

`public string PageJson { get; set; }`

In the view, I want to store it into a JavaScript variable, so I render it as:

```
<script>
    var _pageJson= JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.PageJson)');
</script>
```

The problem I'm having is that this JSON blob spans multiple lines, so when I try to assign it to a variable, it is giving me an error as if I tried to assign a JavaScript variable like this:

```
var _pageJson = '{
  "PageCategories": [
    {
      "CategoryID": 4405958680,
      "Description": "Advertising & Promotions"
    },
//........code continues.........//
```

This of course results in an error after the first bracket since a string can't span multiple lines without either an ending quote and the `+` symbol or the `\` symbol. **How can I get JavaScript to properly populate this variable?** All I can think of is adding a `\` after each line of the JSON in the controller but that seems absolutely ridiculous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this worked for me in the past, I don't have a Windows PC here to test it though.

You will need to encode the JSON value before:

```
var yourModel = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageJson)));
```

No need to have quotes, thanks: @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: I just tried it. I'm sure `@Html.Raw()` and `JSON.parse()` are part of the answer. This converts the `&quot;` escaped characters into actual `"` characters, which is good. However, it still parses out the JSON across multiple lines so I receive the same error.

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe there should be no quotes around JSON... because you know it is JSON already. (there are more approaches with correct implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor )

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe thanks for the edit. Glad I could try to help.

Comment: If `Model.PageJson` is already JSON, there's no need for `JSON.parse` at all. Just simply do `var yourModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageJson));`

Comment: @Rob that was his original answer before my edit. `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PageJson))` seems to return a string such as: `{\r\n  \"MarketplaceCategories\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"CategoryID\": 4405958689,..........` So, in order to remove all the newline & escape characters I had to use `JSON .parse()` and now it is a normal, accessible JS object

Comment: i have two questions. what Json.Encode does and what Html.Raw does ?