# Special characters in JSON are breaking JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

In the ASP MVC controller, I created a ViewBag variable with the list of items to be loaded on my page:

```
    public ActionResult Items()
    {
        ViewBag.itemList = Repo.GetItems(); // Returns list of Items
        return View("Items");
    }
```

On the page side, I am parsing this data:

```
@{
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var jsonData = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, jsonSettings));
var serial = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var items = serial.Serialize(ViewBag.itemList);
}
```

In my Knockout load function, I parse the list and remove newline characters which break the JSON.parse() function.

```
self.load = function () {
var itemsEscaped = '@Html.Raw(items.Replace("'", "\\'"))'.replace("\n", "\\n");
var someItems = JSON.parse(itemsEscaped);
ko.mapping.fromJS(someItems, self.itemMapping, self.someItems);
}
```

However, other special characters occasionally break the JSON.parse() function. Is there a way to filter these out either on the controller on JS side?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/7836439/850825

Comment: I did see that post. I did try the solution there but had issues. Would it not be better to do this on the controller side?

Comment: Please provide an example of the data which are breaking `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: The following will break JSON.parse() in Chrome:  var test = '[{"Description":"0.6g/ml 0.49g/ml USP34<616>\nParticle Size NLT95% Through 80mesh 100%Through 80 mesh USP34<786>\nLoss on drying ≤10.0% 5.2% USP34<731>\nGluten ≤20PPM Complies\nCarrier 50-60%Maltodextrin"}]'.replace("\n", "\\n");

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing Your JSON directly to the page's HTML, You could pass it as a response to a JavaScript request to the server.

If, however, You would like to write it directly in Your cshtml, take a look at this post: [How do I write unencoded Json to my View using Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072762/how-do-i-write-unencoded-json-to-my-view-using-razor), which shows how to print unencoded JSON to the page with some of the special characters encoded not to cause issues with further parsing.

Comment: If i pass JSON as a response (which I do right now in other parts of the projects), I still encounter the issue of parsing JSON with invalid characters.

Comment: And have You tried using `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(/* ... */))` as mentioned in the answer for the question I posted link to?